# Width of the J/$\psi$ resonance

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, mesons, half-life

The [J/$\psi$ resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J/psi_meson) has a mass of ~3 GeV but its width is only of 100 keV, why is it so narrow compared to the total mass? How can the width of these resonances be calculated?

Comment: The width of a resonance is essentially given by the decay rate of the resonating state. The narrower the resonance the more stable the state.

Comment: See [OZI rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OZI_rule).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The small width of the $J/\psi$ was an important discovery, sometimes called the "November Revolution", see ["The Revolution That Shook Particle Physics"](https://www.technologyreview.com/s/531396/the-revolution-that-shook-particle-physics/) (2014-10-21).

It was quickly understood to be due to a new, heavy, quark flavor, called "charm". The $J/\psi$ is a charm-anti-charm bound state with the quantum numbers $J^{PC}=1^{--}$. The reason for the small width is

1. The $J/\psi$ is almost the ground state of the $c\bar{c}$ system. There is a lighter state, called $\eta_c$, but there are no hadronic decays of $J/\psi\to\eta_c$, and the electromagnetic decay width $J/\psi\to\eta_c\gamma$ is small.
2. The $J/\psi$ therefore predominantly decays by $c\bar{c}$ annihilation into light quark pairs (eventually, pions). Because the $J/\psi$ is heavy, this process can be analysed in QCD perturbation theory.
3. The $J/\psi$ is a color singlet and cannot annihilate into a single gluon. It has $J^P=1^-$ and cannot decay into two gluons. The process is therefore $J/\psi\to 3g\to 3(q\bar{q})$, which is proportional to $\alpha_s^3$ (and the wave function of the $c\bar{c}$ pair at the origin). If we treat the $c\bar{c}$ as a color-Coulomb bound state the wave function would bring in extra powers of $\alpha_s$, but the $J/\psi$ is not quite heavy enough to fully justify a perturbative treatment of the wave function. In any case, the large power of $\alpha_s$ explains the small $J/\psi$ width (the $\eta_c$, which can decay into $2g$, is indeed broader).

Comment: I've noticed that often students thirst for crude numbers there. The miracle is that *at that energy scale* ,  $\alpha_s \sim 0.25$. With a color suppression of 0.04, the hadronic 3 gluon width compares to a 1-photon decay EM width going like $\alpha^2$. Thus, very crudely, $\Gamma_{hadronic}/\Gamma_{em}\sim  9$, ***only*** ; so the hadronic decays are only an order of magnitude larger than the EM decays... At the the time, used to strong interactions, people hardly expected their effects to be so fantastically weak and comparable to electromagnetism!